# To get total number of contacts an user have using Google Contact API

Tags: java, google-contacts-api

As we know that there is a limit of **25K contacts** an user can have in his directory. Now I wants to add a new contact to the users directory. Is there any way available to fetch total contact count before adding a new contact to user directory. **I am using Java Google Contact API 3.0.**
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The total number is in feed -> openSearch$totalResults -> $t